# Veneziano amplitude in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, scattering, amplituhedron

It is well-known, that [Veneziano amplitude](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Veneziano+amplitude#:%7E:text=The%20Veneziano%20amplitude%20is%20the,a%20certain%20boundary%202d%20CFT.) is the string scattering amplitude for the scattering of four open bosonic strings in their tachyon states.

**Are some QFT models, in which amplitude is Veneziano amplitude?**

Comment: the Veneziano amplitude is **tree level**, not 1-loop (your reference is wrong).

Answer (score 6):

Well, it was understood early on,

H.B. Nielsen, P. Olesen, *A Parton view on dual amplitudes*,
[Phys Lett **B32** (1970) p. 203](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0370269370904740?token=D91490327E8DABD427F14B5E4DB941F3B6500B68BF4E63A4F32B0369AAC698E872EBBA0CDD258D83902455972A9D5D0B), and

B. Sakita, M.A. Virasoro, *Dynamical model of dual amplitudes*,
[Phys Rev Lett, **24** (1970) p. 1146](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.24.1146?casa_token=M2koMv7KQ6QAAAAA%3Ar1invdAFXbq00fLO9Pf8WlObo32wjiP9yVRQit1dGQIY09hN1MAKUNXERSQmxNjMcakrIWqe3Ie1nw),

that the large *N* approximate systematics of Feynman amps of several field theories, including, eventually, large-*N* (color) QCD, when it came along, would yield Veneziano dual amps.

In this millennium,  after the advent of large-N QCD,

Yu. Makeenko,  and P.  Olesen. *Wilson loops and QCD/string scattering amplitudes.*, [Phys Rev  **D80**   (2009): 026002](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.80.026002?casa_token=C2fIeVl85bYAAAAA%3AimRBoEFnH6NLrakYusRiSMmLVcdoB8MzciWZd8Ws8CodMj-aQfOl_3se_YCRxQGph_YV_13lQjadbg).

and

Adi Armoni, *Large-N QCD and the Veneziano amplitude.*, [Phys Lett **B756** (2016): 328-331](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0370269316300168?token=5F8FA895E6F40D33604CD0E6D45ED69E7A43F473C097F1F966657FBA1F4679930C381587D1E3080B2CE359B21C4CB073).